# WordPress - MultiSite: Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again

Tags: .htaccess, post, media, wordpress

I have problem on my blog: http://osify.com while processing add new post with above error message. I tried to disable all plugins or changed theme, the error is still the same.
I found the issue might link to the media upload, it is not be able to post any image, it's waiting at: "Crunching…" with no continue but the file was in the folder (checked via FTP)

And I already tried to chmod the folder to 777 (before it's 755 for folder, 644 for files)

I think it might link to multi-site issue on shared hosting but no clear idea or clue about that.

My .htaccess

```
#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
[..]
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

It seems just happen when I enable my sub site
Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks for advise,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount your .htaccess is ganked....

REMOVE this part up at the top.

```
    #uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

The ONLY WP calls you should have in there should match this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite

Comment: Thanks, it helps me, tested see: http://osify.com/2012/04/wpmu-be-careful-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: last night, it worked but now not work again seem issue with db but do you understand this: Issues with old WPMU installs

 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?siteN/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]

Comment: OK, I did more: clean-up unused post meta, repair/optimized table/DB.

Add above rule since my site is not on the root of server (via FTP):

   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?siteN/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]

Now fine, my post updated: http://osify.com/2012/04/wpmu-be-careful-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: If I put below code as codex:
`# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]`

I got error again but if I removed it, I can't see my image view / thumbnail after uploaded the image. So what to do?

Comment: Solved by adding this:

`# uploaded files`
`RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?1/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/$2 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Re-uplaod your Wp-admin files 
this will solve your problem

Comment: Already did, got the same error: Can't add new post and media

Comment: The issue might link to media upload but I can't figure out the reason as my sub site: ask.osify.com can post as normal, only the main site of WPMU can't post anything

Comment: I found this link but not yet understand for to do yet [link]http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/obscure-wordpress-errors-why-where-and-how[link]